# "Extract" array from dictionary in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm pretty new to Swift and need your help on a (probably) pretty basic problem.

I have a dictionairy:

```
var dict = ["title" : "Title", "Features" : ["feat1", "feat2", "feat3"], ...]
```

I can create a string from it like so:

```
var headline = dict["title"]! as string
```

but I couldn't manage to create an array. I tried in various combinations:

```
var features = dict["Features"]
var features = dict["Features"]! as Array
var features: Array = dict["Features"]
```

So please enlighten me! How do create an array? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify the type for the array. Either

```
let features = dict["Features"] as [String]
```

or

```
let features = dict["Features"] as Array<String>
```

See the discussion of collection types in [The Swift Language.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID105)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you don't have a type for the array. You describe the type of an array in swift by putting the type name in brackets. In your case, this will be `[String]`. Thus, your code should be `var features = dict["Features"] as [String]` for a mutable array, or use `let` for an immutable array. Hope this helps.